# ¿Cuál seria la forma mas segura de conectarse a una base de datos externa usando ANDROID?

Tags: android

Buenas tardes,

**Explico mas detalladamente el panorama:**

Supongase que estoy desarrollando una aplicacion para android, y este necesite realizar consultas a una base de datos externa (servidor mysql por ejemplo), aunque sea solo por una sola vez.

Estuve surfeando por la web un rato con respecto a este tema, y segun he encontrado, hacer esto desde la misma aplicacion de android **es peligroso** y no es recomendable tal practica. Ya que sostienen que al hacer eso, si alguna persona maliciosa utiliza las herramientas correctas, toman la aplicacion y la decompilan... ya van a tener las credenciales de la base de datos **(Obviamente ya esto es mega peligroso)**.

Se que mas de una aplicacion debe hacer algo de este calibre... hacer un unico proceso de consultas al servidor mysql (SQL SERVER, APACHE, EL QUE SEA) y cargar los datos necesarios a la aplicacion cliente haciendo uso del SQLite.

Entonces caigo con la siguiente pregunta:

**¿Como entonces, podria conectarme a una base de datos externa de forma segura?**

Comment: Usando WebServices, es común en android el uso de WS Rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tal los mecanismos de protección los defines en tu arquitectura, dicho esto es optimo de forma general que las aplicaciones no tengan conexión directa a la BBDD sino que haga una petición a un Servicio Web el cual tenga un Certificado SSL activo que proteja tu comunicación y autenticar los usuarios para poder acceder a la data. [Esto podrías leerlo en este post de IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ssa/webservices/tutorials/ws-radsecurity1/index.html) donde también habla de seguridad de nivel de transporte.

Ahora bien, si por algún motivo tu aplicación permite a un usuario conectarse a una BBDD que configure sos muy dependiente del nivel de seguridad que tenga activa la BBDD, con cual si no viaja por una conexión cifrada un sniffer podría capturar la información; sin embargo podrías impedir que alguien extraiga la cadena de conexión de la aplicación encriptando la data para no dejarlo tan sencillo, ej una llave pública, una contraseña definida por el usuario o hasta en moviles que lo soporten con la huella del usuario haciendo uso del [FingerprintManager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html) en Android.

Answer (score 2):

Cualquier App Android puede ser sujeta de ingenieria inversa, no hay forma de evitar eso, excepto proguard-rules. Así que ese no puede ser tu miedo. Si la transmisión de datos se realiza por un medio que es definitivamente inseguro entonces no tienes forma tampoco de controlar eso y si alguien hackea el server donde está la BD tampoco tiene nada que ver con la App.

Así que realice las consultas a su server desde la App sin miedo, que ese no es el verdadero agujero de seguridad.  Y porque le decompilen la app tampoco se preocupe que las apps están hechas para eso, para ser decompiladas.